# Postgresql - Rows removed by Index

Tags: postgresql

The table in question has a B-tree index on `time`

```
testdb=> explain analyze select avg(gl) from cdstest where time between 1407700790 and 1407711590;
                                                                 QUERY PLAN                                                                  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=1434716.75..1434716.76 rows=1 width=2) (actual time=20106.951..20106.952 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on cdstest  (cost=231261.49..1411280.42 rows=9374529 width=2) (actual time=811.495..10871.963 rows=9438824 loops=1)
         Recheck Cond: (("time" >= 1407700790) AND ("time" <= 1407711590))
         Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 204734
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on timeindex  (cost=0.00..228917.86 rows=9374529 width=0) (actual time=810.108..810.108 rows=9438824 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (("time" >= 1407700790) AND ("time" <= 1407711590))
 Total runtime: 20107.001 ms
(7 rows)
```

`Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 204734` - What does this mean? This seems like a fairly arbitrary number.

Number of rows between the given time range:

```
testdb=> select count(*) from cdstest where time between 1407700790 and 1407711590;
  count  
---------
 9438824
(1 row)
```

The table contains ~60million rows.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The inner `Bitmap Index Scan` node is producing a bitmap, putting `1` to all the places where records that match your search key are found, and `0` otherwise. As your table is quite big, the size of the bitmap is getting bigger, then available memory for these kind of operations, configured via [`work_mem`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-WORK-MEM), becomes small to keep the whole bitmap.

When in lack of a memory, inner node will start producing `1` not for records, but rather for blocks that are known to contain matching records. This means, that outer node `Bitmap Heap Scan` has to read *all* records from such block and re-check them. Obiously, there'll be some non-matching ones, and their number is what you see as `Rows Removed by Index Recheck`.

In the soon coming 9.4 a new feature is added, reporting how many `exact` and/or `lossy` pages where returned by the `Bitmap Index Scan` node. `lossy` are the ones you'd like to avoid. You can check more about this [here](http://michael.otacoo.com/postgresql-2/postgres-9-4-feature-highlight-lossyexact-pages-for-bitmap-heap-scan/).

Finally, consult your `work_mem` setting and try increasing it, just for this particular session.
I assume, that increasing by some 40% should be enough.

---

**EDIT**
I have 9.4beta3 running here, so I prepared a small show case:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tab;
SELECT id, id%10 mod
  INTO tab
  FROM generate_series(1,(1e7)::int) id;
CREATE INDEX i_tab_mod ON tab(mod);
VACUUM ANALYZE tab;
```

Now, I set `work_mem` to the minimal possible value and check it:

```
SET work_mem TO '64kB';
EXPLAIN (analyze, buffers)
SELECT * FROM tab WHERE mod=5;
```

`EXPLAIN` provides the following 2 rows:

```
  Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 8896308
  Heap Blocks: exact=510 lossy=43738
  ...
Execution time: 1356.938 ms
```

Which means, that `64kB` can hold 510 exact blocks. So I calculate the total memory requirement here:

```
new_mem_in_bytes = (work_mem_in_bytes / exact) * lossy
                 = (( 64.0 * 1024 / 510 ) * 43738) / 1024
                 = 5488.7kB
```

This is not precise approach to calculate needed memory, in fact, but I think it is good enough for our needs. So I tried with `SET work_mem TO '5MB'`:

```
  Heap Blocks: exact=44248
  ...
Execution time: 283.466 ms
```

Comment: Very good explanation. I've just learnt something. Had no idea about bitmaps working both in record-level and block-level modes and its relation to work_mem parameter.