# Rails/Postgresql query is slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a query which is causing a lot of problems on with my Rails app. The query which is being run against 1.3 million rows is as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM "products"
INNER JOIN "categories" 
   ON "categories"."id" = "products"."category_id"
WHERE "products"."disabled" = 'f'
  AND (categories.is_adult = 't'
  AND merchant_image_url is NOT NULL
  AND advertiser_id in (1,3,8,9,12,16,17,18,24,27,31,32,34,40,44,47,48,53,55,57,61,64
              ,69,78,79,80,81,85,89,91,95,98,102,110,113,114,119,127,128,130,133,134))
```

The slow part of the query is:

```
advertiser_id in (1,3,8,9,12,16,17,18,24,27,31,32,34,40,44,47,48,53,55,57,61,64,
               69,78,79,80,81,85,89,91,95,98,102,110,113,114,119,127,128,130,133,134))
```

There is an index on `advertiser_id`

This is the users preferences and is variable. Without this the query runs blazingly fast.

Please ask for any other information if I've not supplied it and I will add it as soon as I can. Thanks in advance!

**Update 1**
Here is the Query Plan:

```
Aggregate  (cost=198184.75..198184.76 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=11942.818..11942.818 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=8065.09..197269.21 rows=366218 width=0) (actual time=110.651..11821.545 rows=349373 loops=1)
        Hash Cond: (products.category_id = categories.id)
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on products  (cost=8047.13..192215.75 rows=366218 width=4) (actual time=109.655..11470.039 rows=349373 loops=1)
              Recheck Cond: (advertiser_id = ANY ('{1,3,8,9,12,16,17,18,24,27,31,32,34,40,44,47,48,53,55,57,61,64,69,78,79,80,81,85,89,91,95,98,102,110,113,114,119,127,128,130,133,134}'::integer[]))
              Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 459153
              Filter: ((NOT disabled) AND (merchant_image_url IS NOT NULL))"
              Rows Removed by Filter: 112084
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_products_on_advertiser_id  (cost=0.00..7955.57 rows=465290 width=0) (actual time=106.865..106.865 rows=461457 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (advertiser_id = ANY ('{1,3,8,9,12,16,17,18,24,27,31,32,34,40,44,47,48,53,55,57,61,64,69,78,79,80,81,85,89,91,95,98,102,110,113,114,119,127,128,130,133,134}'::integer[]))
        ->  Hash  (cost=11.87..11.87 rows=487 width=4) (actual time=0.944..0.944 rows=487 loops=1)
              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 18kB
              ->  Seq Scan on categories  (cost=0.00..11.87 rows=487 width=4) (actual time=0.007..0.616 rows=487 loops=1)
Total runtime: 11943.149 ms
```

and the Explain

[image]

Comment: Is there an index on the `advertiser_id`?

Comment: Ah yes! I meant to say there is an index on advertiser_id

Comment: advertiser_id is in categories table?

Comment: You'll need an index on `category_id, disabled` for `products` as well as one on `advertiser_id`, and `is_adult`. Basically anything that shows up in your `WHERE` conditions.

Comment: No - It's in the **products** table

Comment: Even though you have the index, Postgresql may not choose to use it. Use `explain` either in psql or rails c console to see how Postgresql execute the query and if Postgresql used the index. Also my thinking is, it might speed up if you put `advertiser_id in ..` in the first line under the first AND

Comment: The EXPLAIN output for that query would be useful. As would the schemas (including indexes). Where does that list of `advertiser_id`s come from? My first guess is that that should be another JOIN. Indexes may or may not be useful depending on the column statistics.

Comment: I've update the post with the relevant details.

Comment: When you see `Rows Removed by Index Recheck` you know there is something wrong, an index fetch should not need a recheck. Hopefully, there is already an answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26418715/postgresql-rows-removed-by-index
It seems that your index is too fat for your work_mem, either drop this index (PostgreSQL will use a less filtering index but this could boost your query) OR boost your work_mem